# How can I make the player go forward? (Ursina Python)

Tags: python, ursina

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        self.controller = Entity(
            model = 'cube',
            parent = camera
        )
        super().__init__(parent=self.controller)
        
    def update(self):
        if held_keys['a']:
            camera.rotation_y -= 50 * time.dt
            self.controller.rotation_y = camera.rotation_y
            if camera.rotation_y < -360: camera.rotation_y = 0
            
        if held_keys['d']:
            camera.rotation_y += 50 * time.dt
            self.controller.rotation_y = camera.rotation_y
            if camera.rotation_y > 360: camera.rotation_y = 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: use the built-in [FirstPersonController](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#FirstPersonController)?

Answer (score 1):

```py
entity = Entity(model='cube')

def update():
    entity.position += entity.forward
```